# Stuck at "Dependency Graph, done." in react-native npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When I do `react-native init` > `npm start` in the terminal of an empty folder, I get this:

> > SATPractice@0.0.1 start C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\test
> >     node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start
>
> Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\test\node_modules (40ms)
>   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
>   │
>   │ │  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.
>   │ │
>   │ │  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free
>   to        │ │  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you
>   prefer.               │ │
>   │ │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native
>   │ │
>   │
>   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>
> Looking for JS files in    C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\test
>
> Metro Bundler ready.
>
> Loading dependency graph, done.

Then it just hangs there.. forever. I tried waiting 30 minutes, still nothing. I'm on Windows 10, react version 0.55.3, and npm 5.5.1.

Comment: try `react-native upgrade`, it fixed it for me,

Comment: Have you run `react-native run-android` to actually launch the app on an emulator? The bundler itself will just sit there until an RN app tries to connect to it.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following the steps in the "[Getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)" section of the react-native docs?

Comment: Yeah, the `create-react-native-app` works fine, but that's an example package. I'd like to use the normal (`react-native init`), which doesn't work.